# Change ImageView image multiple times within a for loop during a onClick function?

Tags: android, button, onclick, imageview, onclicklistener

So far, when I change image within the onClick function, the image does not change until the onClick function ends. Is there a way to change the image multiple times during the onClick function? What I would like to do is, on each of the function calls within the on Click (i.e. LetterS, etc.) is have the image change. 
See Code Below...

MainActivity:

```js
imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (isflash) {
                    LetterS();
                    LetterO();
                    LetterS();
                    imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.sos_btn);

                } else {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    builder.setTitle("Message...");
                    builder.setMessage("Flashlight is NOT Available on this device...");
                    builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            finish();
                        }
                    });
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                    alertDialog.show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void LetterS() {
        imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ltr_s);
        for (int l = 1; l <= 3; l += 1) {
            parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
            camera.setParameters(parameters);
            camera.startPreview();
            // We make the thread sleeping
            android.os.SystemClock.sleep(300);

            parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
            camera.setParameters(parameters);
            camera.stopPreview();
            // We make the thread sleeping
            android.os.SystemClock.sleep(200);
        }
        android.os.SystemClock.sleep(300);
    }

    public void LetterO() {
        imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ltr_o);
        for (int l = 1; l <= 3; l += 1) {
            parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
            camera.setParameters(parameters);
            camera.startPreview();
            // We make the thread sleeping
            android.os.SystemClock.sleep(1000);

            parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
            camera.setParameters(parameters);
            camera.stopPreview();
            // We make the thread sleeping
            android.os.SystemClock.sleep(200);
        }
        android.os.SystemClock.sleep(500);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `SystemClock#sleep(long)` in your main thread (also called UI thread). This is the very same thread that handles all the interaction with the user. If you block this thread, your user is unable to perform any action with your app.

Instead you can use methods like `View#post(Runnable)`, `View#postDelayed(Runnable, long)`, `Handler#post(Runnable)` or `Handler#postDelayed(Runnable, long)` to schedule tasks to be performed later.

Let me demonstrate the usage of these methods for a simpler subset of your problem: you have an ImageButton, and you want to display sequentially a set of images to the user after they click a button (so we ignore the flashlight for simplicity).

Let's say we want an image to change every 300 milliseconds:

```
private static final long IMAGE_UPDATE_DELAY_MILLIS = 300;
```

And we have the following set of drawable resources to show:

```
private static final int[] ALL_DRAWABLE_RES = new int[] {
    R.drawable.ltr_s,
    R.drawable.ltr_o,
    R.drawable.ltr_s
};
```

Finally we need several other fields we are going to use:

```
private int currentDrawableResIndex;
private ImageButton imageButton;
private Runnable updateImageTask;
```

In our `onCreate` we are going to initialize our fields:

```
updateImageTask = new UpdateImageTask();

imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.image_button);
imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        currentDrawableResIndex = 0;
        imageButton.setImageResource(ALL_DRAWABLE_RES[0]);
        imageButton.removeCallbacks(updateImageTask);
        imageButton.postDelayed(updateImageTask, IMAGE_UPDATE_DELAY_MILLIS);
    }
}
```

We are going to implement `UpdateImageTask` in a moment - it is going to be a `Runnable` doing the job. In `onClick` we just cancel any ongoing tasks and start the whole process over. Our `Runnable` is posted in the UI thread's "message queue" and will be executed later.

In our `onStop` we are going also to cancel the process - the Activity is no longer visible to the user.

```
imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.my_default_drawable);
imageButton.removeCallbacks(updateImageTask);
```

Finally here is our `Runnable`:

```
private class UpdateImageTask implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        currentDrawableResIndex++;

        if (currentDrawableResIndex < ALL_DRAWABLE_RES.length) {
            imageButton.setImageResource(ALL_DRAWABLE_RES[currentDrawableResIndex]);
            imageButton.postDelayed(this, IMAGE_UPDATE_DELAY_MILLIS);
        } else {
            imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.my_default_drawable);
        }
    }
}
```

So we simply repost the `Runnable` if there are more images to show, and clean up after we are done.

In a similar way you can include the flashlight blinks into your code.

Comment: Marcin Jedynak - Thanks for your reply. Will try with your recommendations.............

Comment: Marcin Jedynak - UPDATE: That worked, images now showing..Thanks again for your help..................